# For Each instruction based on a dynamic array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, foreach

I'm currently experiencing the following problem:

```
For Each item In Array
    If isItemInTheArray(Array, item) Then
       removeItem(Array, item)
    End If
Next
```

But the problem is, when removing the current item (i.e. index = 0), the next item which should be taken by the for each is still index 0 and not the index 1.

To sum up, in vb.net, how to tell to "for each" that the next item it should take is still the first one (i.e. index 0) and not the obvious next one (i.e. index 1)?

EDIT:
Maybe I could be more specific.

I have many pieces of music in my drive which are stock like following:

- Each .mp3 file is in a folder like "Blob-release2018\blob.mp3"
- Each music folder contains different types of file like ".mp3", ".nfo" or ".jpg"
- Some music has 2 version : "extended" for DJing and "edited" for radio broadcasting
- Some music folder contains albums, so different .mp3 but not the same music...

I want to scan my all music path and populate a grid view with ".mp3" files. But if I have 2 version of a song, I need only 1 line with a "version extd" / "version edit" checkbox checked to show which version I have....

EDIT: Problem solved by using a custom class and check before adding in a collection. Thanks to @Craig ! More details in comment zone

Comment: You could use a `Queue(Of T)`. Then use [`Dequeue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue.dequeue?view=netframework-4.7.2) while `queue.Count > 0`.

Comment: Whatever you do, you shouldn't be using an array. If you want FIFO functionality then you should be using a `Queue`. If you want LIFO functionality then you should be using a `Stack`.  Otherwise you should be using a `List`.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by a "dynamic array"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I need to remove the first item in my collection, I also need (some times) to remove an item at a specific index. `Queue(Of T)` or `Stack(Of T)` allows to remove an item at a specific index ?

Comment: @Jarhead It sounds like you need to use a List for the collection. Then, to remove items, use a For loop and count *down* from the end (yourList.Count() - 1) to 0 and remove items as required.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to modify a collection while you are iterating it (i.e. using `For Each`).  This will often lead to an exception.  If you are going to modify the collection, then you need to use a loop, and you need to make sure that your loop strategy will work correctly in the presence of the changes (e.g. looping backwards or using a While loop).

Comment: For what you want to do, it seems like the right way to handle this is up-front instead of by post-processing the list.  Store an object instead of a filename (and since you want to be able to get back to it, you probably want an associative collection like a `Dictionary`), create the objects as you scan, check for extended/edited, check for if the item already exists, insert if not, otherwise update the extended/edited flag.

Comment: @Craig you're right... I'm experiencing a lot of exception...

Comment: @Craig, your solution sounds good, but I've not well understood it. Should I store `FileInfo` instead of fileName ? And then add it to the collection only if match with my criteria ?

Comment: I'd say a custom class type, with `Name`, `IsExtended`, `IsEdited`, etc.  Process each filename to see if it is extended, edited, etc. and strip off the part that indicates that, then see if the file is already in your `Dictionary` (which should be indexed by name), if not, add it, if it is, edit it with the updated flag.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try this. 
Once done, is that possible to link a GridView to a `List(of myCustomClass)` to fill it automatically ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Data binding is designed for this use case.

Comment: @Craig it works very well !!! Thanks a lot for your advise, this was exactly what I was looking for :) 

Thnaks to everybody else who had take the time to help me :)